# Merging messages using spring-integration

Tags: spring-integration

From a channel.

```
<!-- messages missing a vital piece of information -->
<int:channel id="inChannel" />
```

I have an activator to read the messages.

```
<!-- read the message and prepare an http request for the extra information -->
<int:service-activator 
    input-channel="inChannel"
    output-channel="additionalInformationOutChannel"
    ref="additionalInformationEndpointImpl"
    method="prepare" > 
</int:service-activator>
```

Now the original message is missing a vital piece of information.  The only way to get it is by requesting it from an external system via http.

```
<!-- login -->
<int-http:outbound-gateway
      url="http://...login?username=...&password=..."
      http-method="..." />

<!-- get information -->
<int-http:outbound-gateway
      url="http://...extraInfomration"
      http-method="GET"
      expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
      request-channel="additionalInformationOutChannel"  />

<!-- logout -->
<int-http:outbound-gateway
      url="http://...logout?username=..."
      http-method="..." />
```

I need some way to combine the above http response with the original message so that I can update the original message with the additional information.

Actually the process is as follows

1. Read message from `inChannel`
2. Login to external system via http
3. Request information from external system as json payload via http
4. Logout of external system via http
5. Update the original message from `inChannel` with some information from the json payload.

How can I create a flow that links all the together?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [content (payload) enricher](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher). The http request would be performed on the `request-channel` flow and the result can be use to enrich the payload and/or headers of the original message. For example, if the original payload has a setter `setAdditionalInformation` the enricher can set that property from data in the result from the http interaction.